# Mod rewrite .htaccess - several redirections HTTP &HTTPS

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I have domain1.com as my "main" domain, which is also document root. Every other domain (domain2.com, domain3.net, etc.) are directly linked to domain1.com as an alias.

Some of those domains I've bought for friends to redirect to their webspaces. I use the following rules for that:

```
# domain4.de -> externaldomain.com
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?domain4.de$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*) http://externaldomain.com/$1 [L,R]
```

I also redirect ALL domains to the https:// equivalent of the root domain, also stripping www. I've also included an old subdomain to redirect, since it's no longer used. I've been using this rule for that:

```
# Redirect alias Sites to HTTPS @ domain1.com
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?domain1.net$ [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?domain1.com$ [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?domain1.de$ [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?domain2.de$ [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?domain2.com$ [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^blog.domain1.com$ [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^blog.domain1.net$ [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^blog.domain1.de$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://domain1.com/$1 [L,R=301]
```

For HTTP -> HTTPS redirect I've been using the following rule:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R,L]
```

And that's the rule that possibly needs altertering, since I've been trying to EXCLUDE a single domain from it - since the SSL Certificate is a *.domain1.com HTTPS cannot be used for this domain.

This rule redirects the domain5.com to domain1.com/subdir while keeping the domain5.com in the address bar:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?domain5\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule !^subdir/ /subdir%{REQUEST_URI} [L,NC]
```

I've tried to use this rule, but it doesn't do anything.

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^(www\.)?domain5.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R,L]
```

If any of the above rules could be combined/optimized I would also appreciate any suggestions. I'm not really into expressions and have "hacked" together most things by trial and error...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do that:

```
# domain4.de -> externaldomain.com
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?domain4.de$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*) http://externaldomain.com/$1 [L,R]

# Redirect alias Sites and http to HTTPS @ domain1.com without domain5
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^(www\.)?domain5\.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^domain1.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://domain1.com/$1 [L,R=301]

# Redirects the domain5.com to domain1.com/subdir
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?domain5\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule !^subdir/ /subdir%{REQUEST_URI} [L,NC]
```

Comment: Thank you very much.That workds like a charm (when I finally deleted my browser cache ..... stupid me).

Comment: if I may add an additional question - how do I handle subdomains with this? The subdomains at my hoster are virtual directories named ".sub-name", so if I'd like to create a subdomain named "foo" I just create a dir named ".sub-foo".

I've tried RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^(*\.)?shark5060.net$ [NC] which actually catches the subdomain, but I've no idea how the RewriteRule should look like.

Comment: You can use: `RewriteRule ^(.*)$       /.sub-%1/$1 [NC]`

Comment: Ah well maybe my explanation was unclear: Your code (the old one) would result in https://domain.com/.sub-foo/<request> , which actually works, but doesn't look very nice.

I would like: https://foo.domain.com/<request>

Comment: I understood it. With your link apache use my RewriteRule to show the real page.

Comment: To my understanding the following code should do what I need.
(since subdomains are already handled internally by my hoster, there is no need to handle the redirection in the .htaccess).

[link](http://htaccess.madewithlove.be/) shows everything should work fine, but I get an error :/

Comment: Redirects the domain5.com to domain1.com/subdir
`RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?domain5\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule !^subdir/ /subdir%{REQUEST_URI} [L]`


redircet all subdomains to HTTPS
`RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(.*\.)?domain1.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%1domain1.com/$1 [R]`

filter out www subdromain
`RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)domain1.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://domain1.com/$1 [L,R]`